# bind parameter in oracle EBS

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oraclereports, oracle-ebs

i need to add list of values to a bin parameter on report builder in oracle e-business suite

but in this list of values i need the first option is `all` and other values are result of select statement like the following:

```
all
10
20
30
....
```

so if the user clicked on "all" the report will query all departments
if the user clicked on any other specific department, the report will query this specific department

how can i add this "all" option??

Answer (score 0):

I don't use EBS, but I do know Reports and some SQL so - here's my suggestion.

Adding the "all" option is simple - `union` it with other values. Something like this:

```
SQL> select value
  2  from (select 1 rn, 'all' value from dual
  3        union all
  4        select 2 rn, to_char(deptno) from dept
  5       )
  6  order by rn, value;

VALUE
----------------------------------------
all
10
20
30
40

SQL>
```

Then, in a query, you'd use it as

```
select e.deptno, e.ename, e.job
from emp e
where e.deptno = case when :par_deptno = 'all' then to_char(e.deptno)
                      else :par_deptno
                 end
order by e.deptno, e.ename;
```

---

The above example, ran in SQL*Plus (so don't mind a substitution instead of a bind variable):

First, I'm passing `10`:

```
SQL> select e.deptno, e.ename, e.job
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.deptno = case when '&&par_deptno' = 'all' then to_char(e.deptno)
  4                        else '&&par_deptno'
  5                   end
  6  order by e.deptno, e.ename;
Enter value for par_deptno: 10

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK
```

Now, let's try `all`:

```
SQL> undefine par_deptno
SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: all

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me. Now, how will it look like in EBS, I have no idea.

Comment: it worked in similar way, i get the "all" value union with the query that returns the departments and then in the report query i typed a where condition if the parameter value is all then it returns all values, if not the it will be a specific dept id therefor return that department

Comment: Good, I'm glad to hear that.